How does persistent browser caching work internally?
What does this option do internally?

Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance in caching

And when does it reload new HTML / CSS into a user's mobile device?
When updating a Lightning Web Component, do we need to inform the users to clear their cache with this option enabled? Or will it be updated periodically by itself?
Would anyone be able to shed some more light on this option please?
Addition 02/07/2024
I am not able to clear cache on devices without clearing the Salesforce app Data storage, which clears the local storage and requires re-login

What the option does is exactly what it says: enables caching on the client side (the users' browsers) to improve performance by reducing the number of calls to Salesforce's servers. This includes not only page loads but also data retrieved by components.
The explanation on how it works is not in the documentation, but you can get some hints by visiting the pages about caching. The note on "Enable Secure Browser Caching" states, for example, that "disabling secure and persistent browser caching has a significant negative performance impact on Lightning Experience." And that you may wish to disable it in the scenarios where the "company doesn't allow browser caching, even if the data is encrypted" (the hint here is in the "even if the data is encrypted" bit, which implies caching works not just for the components themselves but the data they load).
Also, the page on the AuraEnabled annotation states that the "client-side storage is automatically configured in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce mobile app" and that the components "shouldn't assume a cache duration" because Salesforce optimizes the platform. In this case, it is implied by the note that the cache duration is dynamic and can't be changed by the administrator of the Salesforce org.
So for your second question: when does it reload new things? We don't know. All we do know is that it takes some time. But the Enable Secure Browser Caching page has a note that states that an user can see the changes immediately if they "log out and log back in" and that "other users don't see the change until the cache is deleted or invalidated", which we don't know how long it takes because it is not specified, unfortunately.
